# Excel 365 - retain all changes to a file beyond 60 days

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365

Our order review process requires that we be able to tell when a company rep has corrected or changed anything on an order form. The order form is currently an Excel 365 spreadsheet.

A recent revision to the order form upgraded the file to using the Save Changes functionality in Excel 365. While training the order team, we found the documentation saying that Save Changes will only retain changes for 60 days.

We are a manufacturer of industrial equipment, and we regularly need to consult order forms from 20+ years ago.

I'm pretty sure there isn't a solution which is native to Excel. I'm looking for a third party add-in or tool which would allow us to retain the detailed change history on an individual cell basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Microsoft articles have information about setting an
arbitrary number of days for tracking history:

- [Track changes in a Shared Workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-22aea671-cac7-4fa3-845d-eeb23725bd15)
- [What happened to shared workbooks?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-happened-to-shared-workbooks-150fc205-990a-4763-82f1-6c259303fe05)

This is the summary of both articles.

**Setting the number of days to track**

- Click the "Share Workbook" icon
  (hidden by default in newer versions of Excel)
- In the "Share Workbook" dialog, Edit tab, check
  "Use the old shared workbooks feature instead of the new co-authoring
  experience"
- In the Advanced tab click "Keep change history for:" and
  enter the number of days
- Click OK (you may be asked to save the workbook).

The article notes :

> By default, Excel keeps the change history for 30 days and permanently erases any change history that is older than this number of days. To keep change history for a longer than 30 days, enter a number that is larger than 30.

**Add the "Shared Workbook" feature back to Excel**

If your version of Excel is too new and does not have the
"Shared Workbook" feature, here is how to enable it again:

- Click *File > Options > Quick Access Toolbar*
- Under "Choose commands from" select "All Commands"
- Click and Add the icons for "Share Workbook (Legacy)"
  and "Track Changes (Legacy)".

Answer (score 0):

I use Excel 365 and have done for a long time. Ordinary changes are saved beyond 60 days, in fact, permanently. I sync files back and forth and would instantly see changes.

If you are using a table, data entry or shared workbook method that is different that the above, then save files in a new name in folders you set up for this purpose.

In other words, be certain you have good backups. Good backups prevent problems and should be used.

I have shared workbooks in Sharepoint for a Council budget and changes are not expiring.